# Bibliography: Remove dot from author and note, and add dot to title

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents

So i have this APA style bibliography for online sources:

[12] Unity Technologies. (2023). Unity Manual https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityManual.html.

I want it to be like this:

[12] Unity Technologies (2023). Unity Manual. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityManual.html

How can i achive that only for @online bibliography?

BTW i'm using biblatex with this setting:

```
\usepackage[style=apa, citestyle=numeric, backend=biber, sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

and this other settings to remove square brackets, letter after date and orderding with numbers:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
  
\DeclareFieldFormat{extradate}{\iffieldnums{labelyear}{}{\apashortdash\mknumalph{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{addinfo2}{%
  %% \printtexte[brackets]{%
    \iffieldbibstring{entrysubtype}
      {\bibcplstring{\thefield{entrysubtype}}}
      {\printfield{entrysubtype}}%
    \setunit*{\addsemicolon\addspace}%
    \printfield{note}
  %% }
}
```